# PHP-Strings containing space output

Tags: php, html, mysql, web

I have 2 files. "index.php" and "output.php". Inside index.php I have a dropdown-list containing all Italian cities that was obtained from mysql table. Scope of my test is to select a city from dropdown-list and send value to output.php that print the value.

this is my code:

-index.php:

```
    <form action="output.php" method="post">
<div align="center">
<?php
echo "Questa è una prova";

// Open db connection
$con = mysqli_connect ( "127.0.0.1", "root", "", "test" );

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno ( $con )) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error ();
}

echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";
echo "</br>";

//Query principale
$result = mysqli_query ( $con, "SELECT * FROM it_cities" );
?>

<select name="fcity">
<?php 
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo '<option value='  . $row['comuni'] .  '>' . $row['comuni'] . '</option>';
    echo "<br>";
}
?>
</select>
</br>
<input type="submit" value="Invia">
</div>
</form>
```

---

-output.php:

```
   <?php

$city= $_REQUEST ['fcity'] ;

echo "$city" ;

?>
```

My problem is with strings containing space (example "Abano Terme", only "Abano" is printed on the screen).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're missing quotes around your `option` elements.

```
echo '<option value='  . $row['comuni'] .  '>' . $row['comuni'] . '</option>';
                    ^----------------------^
```

Change it to

```
echo '<option value="'  . $row['comuni'] .  '">' . $row['comuni'] . '</option>';
```